# Group following fields by matched header line using Awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have an output of a cli tool that gives me a list like this one:

```
Listing accountBrand
  [2020-03-24 18:03:42] 20200211204415-create-accountBrand.js : Initial creation of accountBrand
  [2020-03-24 18:03:45] 20200323215802-example-entry.js : <Put your description here>
Listing baseBrand
  [pending]             20200211202306-create-baseBrand.js : Initial creation of base brand
Listing loginRegistrationInit
  [2020-03-24 14:03:41] 20200211204431-create-loginRegistrationInit.js : Initial creation of login registration init
Listing newsletterOptin
  [pending]             20200211204354-create-newletter-optin.js : Initial creation of newsletter optin
Listing test
  [pending]             testMigration.js : <No Description>
```

I would like to have an associative array with keys set to those words after the word `Listing`, and filenames would end up being elements of each of those respectively.

So basically the list above would make an array `a`, with the following content:

```
a['accountBrand'] = ['20200211204415-create-accountBrand.js', '20200323215802-example-entry.js']
a['loginRegistrationInit'] = ['20200211204431-create-loginRegistrationInit.js']
...
```

I came up with something like this:

```
cat list | awk '/Listing/ {k=$2; next;}; {a[k]+=$2} END {print a["accountBrand"]}'
```

but as a result I get:

```
36
```

...while `a['newsletterOptin']` will contain `20200211204354` as value

because I cannot refer always to `$2` as sometimes I have [pending] and other times [2020-03-24 18:03:42] as first field.

Obviously not what I wanted, instead of two filenames being appended as strings, I got the sum of the above filenames after they are being casted to number.

I would like to have output formatted in a way that I can clearly tell which filenames are tied to a particular listing, so something like this:

```
accountBrand filename1, filename2
newsletterOptin filename1
baseBrand filename1, filename2, filename3
...
```

Comment: @Quasímodo yes you are right, just saw that, I am going to correct the example.

Comment: The + does a decimal conversion and addition: strings are concatenated just because they are adjacent. However, to get a separator use: a[k] = a[k] "," $2; This will put a spare separator at the front where a[k] is initially empty: get rid of this when you output by: print substr (a["name"], 2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're asking for help with?

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^ / {
    sub(/.*]/,"")
    fnames[$1]
    next
}
{ if (NR>1) prt(); key = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    printf "%s", key
    for (fname in fnames) {
        printf " %s", fname
    }
    print ""
    delete fnames
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
accountBrand 20200211204415-create-accountBrand.js 20200323215802-example-entry.js
baseBrand 20200211202306-create-baseBrand.js
loginRegistrationInit 20200211204431-create-loginRegistrationInit.js
newsletterOptin 20200211204354-create-newletter-optin.js
test testMigration.js
```

or is it specifically this implementation:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^ / {
    sub(/.*]/,"")
    fnames[key] = (key in fnames ? fnames[key] OFS : "") $1
    next
}
{ key = $2 }
END {
    for (key in fnames) {
        print key, fnames[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
loginRegistrationInit 20200211204431-create-loginRegistrationInit.js
baseBrand 20200211202306-create-baseBrand.js
accountBrand 20200211204415-create-accountBrand.js 20200323215802-example-entry.js
newsletterOptin 20200211204354-create-newletter-optin.js
test testMigration.js
```

or something else?

Comment: Thanks Ed, thats exactly what I had in mind, although I cannot tell the difference between the two, don't they give the same result? If so, I prefer the second one. Would you mind explaining shortly the logic behind this?

Comment: They give the same output but the first is printing the list of file names every time a new key is seen while the second is building the associative array mentioned in your question that contains a list of file names per key index. The latter uses more memory as it has to store everything in memory until it's all processed together in the END and it doesn't treats duplicate file names per key as separate file names while the former would make a unique list. The former prints the keys in input order but shuffles the files while the latter prints the files in order per key but shuffles the keys.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter, as duplicates are not allowed within the same listing, also a list will always be very short, containing just a few entries so, not much memory wasted.

Comment: I don't get it, when this line of code gets executed `{ key = $2 }`? Are those blocks of code embraced with `{}` run for every line of input, or sequentially? I am referring to the second version.

Comment: The `/^ / { foo; next }` block is executed for every line that starts with a blank, the other block `{ key=$2 }` is executed for the rest of the lines courtesy of the `next` in the other block. You can always add `print` statements within each block to see when they get hit.